# NPX create-react-app with Error: spawn UNKNOWN

Tags: reactjs

i install node.js then trying to create first react app by using npx create-react-app my-app in power shell and it cames following error.

```
PS C:\Users\Owner> npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Owner\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:420:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:733:9)
    at spawn (C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
    at C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:383:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at install (C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:334:10)
    at C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:461:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from C:\Users\Owner
Done.
PS C:\Users\Owner>
```

I have been searching for solutions for hours and tried different methods but still didn't work. Can anyone please help?
node --version
v16.18.0
npm --version
8.19.2

Thanks in advance

Comment: What anti virus are you using, try disabling it while running that command.

Comment: uninstall all antivirus. only windows security left